# Internet Explorer 11 Mousewheel Zoom doesn't work

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Internet Explorer 11 mouse wheel Zoom doesn't work on google maps api v3.
This is the latest version of IE

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport)?  IE11 is _not_ officially supported `For desktop:
Internet Explorer 8–10 inclusive (Windows)` (at this time).

Answer (score 4):

Workaround META page code: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />`
I assume this mouse wheel bug will be resolved in due course.

Answer (score 2):

While geocodezip is technically correct in pointing out it's not officially supported per the documentation on the maps page, I suspect that the page just hasn't been updated yet as there are at least two defects already reported on this issue in new state:

[defect 6071](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6071)
[defect 5944](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5944)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while having this issue myself. I was using Google Maps API v3.12, but once I upgraded to the current release (3.15) it seemed to fix this problem.